# SQL Server: Displaying result in Java Textfield

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, swing

I use MS SQL Server and Java with JDBC to connect.
I don't know how to display the result of my simple SQL queries in a Java Texfield. Displaying my data in a JTable is no problem with the external JAR **rs2xml**.

That works and prints my table in the panel.

```
String MaxQuery = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(MaxQuery);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

**But** when i want to display a simple query like "*SELECT AVG(budget) FROM Employees*" with 1 result, i want to print this **in a textfield**.

The method setModel doesn't work with Textfields. So i have tried something like that:

```
String AVGQuery = "SELECT AVG(budget) FROM Employees";
PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(AVGQuery);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
textFieldAns.setText(rs.toString());
```

But that prints me "SQLServerResultSet:1". I want the result, and not the number of results. Hope u can help me by my little problem :).

Comment: [Here you can find more details on how to use a ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)

Comment: In the future, consider searching a little on this. A simple look at the ResultSet API would answer this quickly for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use code similar to

```
if (rs.next()) {
    textFieldAns.setText(rs.getString("column name you want to print");
}
```

Here is s good example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Comment: The problem is, there is no column name for this result. When i say "SELECT AVG(budget) FROM Employees" the column name is not defined.

Comment: You can specify the column by index, `getString(int)`; just remember, in JDBC it's 1 indexed, not 0 indexed like the rest of the Java API

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was my problem. I do that hours ago, but i ever used 0...